# Google Sign-In Failed Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My authentication with Google **sign-in** don't work. It works fine before a migrate to Firebase. This is my code:

> **Note:** google-service.json  ID of my App is note the same as Web id I don't know if I get the correct one or note.

```
  public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
 private SignInButton signInButton;
  private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
  private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;
  GoogleSignInAccount acct = null;
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  String TAG="AUTH";
  gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))
            .requestIdToken("******************************")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
  signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());
    signInButton.setColorScheme(SignInButton.COLOR_LIGHT);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /*   OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent =    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  System.out.println("REQUEST=======" + requestCode);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result =    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);

   }
    }

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct);
        test();
        Intent accueil = new Intent(this, UpDateDB.class);
        startActivity(accueil);
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential =    GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
   .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" +   task.isSuccessful());

          if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential",    task.getException());
               Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == signInButton) {
        if(!ConnexionInternet.isConnectedInternet(this)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Pas De Connexion",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
              signIn();
           }

        }
     }
 }
```

These are my dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.17.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
   } 
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: What is the error from the stack trace?

Comment: this is the problem there is no stack

Comment: it's work now on my emulator, i replaced  .requestIdToken("******************************") By 
.requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id)) But on release APK don't